# Stack Overflow silently signed me out as I applied for a job

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I spent considerable time working on a job application on Stack Overflow jobs. I appeared to be signed in the whole time as I could see my icon and was doing other Stack Overflow things.

I uploaded my resumé, pressed submit... And got an error that I hadn't uploaded my resumé. I felt something was wrong, and it's my bet that I was actually logged out at that point, although I didn't note the presence or absence of my icon.

I re-added the resumé and pressed submit, and to my annoyance, it submitted the job application, and then asked me to create a Stack Overflow account - now my icon was definitely gone and I was definitely logged out.

The confirmation email makes it clear that I did not apply from my Stack Overflow account.

I had the form up partly filled out for several days - it's my guess that that's the source of the issue. But the handling was not correct. When I submitted from the stale page, it should ask me to sign in again, not secretly sign me out and then send the application. (And I have kept Stack Overflow pages up for weeks in the past without getting signed out.)

More, I'd like to now send a follow-up message with my Stack Overflow account, but there's no way to do that...

This is on MacOS 10.12, Chrome, with an unlimited cookie retention policy (every few months I clean them out by hand).

Comment: I also had signed in altogether for around a month on same device because I visited site everyday but got signed out automatically on page refreshing. Maybe there's a time limit to stay logged in.

Comment: @Gourav: That's my best guess too - I coincidentally hit some limit and got logged out.  Still, "it" should know I've been signed out and try to sign me back in, or warm me, or something.  Job hunting is stressful anyway, "the worst parts of dating and without the alcohol". :-)

Comment: Yes there must be a notification for that

Comment: I haven't used Jobs but I've been logged in for months at a time. Unless there is something special about Jobs, I don't think the site limits how long you can stay logged in.

Comment: Your browser, the version, and your OS should be added to the question as well as the settings for cookies in your browser. What's your browser's retention policy for cookies? Is it set to clear your history automatically?

Comment: @BSMP all good questions - I answered them.  In particular, I just made sure that my browser was not, in fact, deleting cookies (which it wasn't).